# Can't drop TreeNode on empty <p:tree> component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using two separated `<p:tree>` components. When you click a `commandButton` the application adds a new node into the first tree. This part works fine.

Now what I want to do is drag and drop nodes between these trees. It works perfectly if there is at least one element in the target tree, but nothing happens if that tree is empty -and yes, both trees must be empty at the beginning-. The thing is I know this can be done [because of this example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/dragdrop.xhtml). My code is almost exactly the same and I can't figure out the reason it doesn't work for me. Both trees are like this, except for the `value` attribute of course:

```
<p:tree value="#{signLinesLists.createdSignLinesRoot}"
var="node" draggable="true" droppable="true"
dragdropScope="signLinesScope" selectionMode="single">
        <p:ajax event="dragdrop" listener="#{signLinesLists.onDragDrop}" />
        <p:treeNode>
            <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
        </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

The listener in the `ajax event` is just for debugging purposes and has no effects on the bean attributes so I presume it can be ignored.

What am I missing?

Comment: I know it's quite old, but we are facing the same issue on Primefaces 4.0.10. Did you manage to solve it?